# Combining active record relations

Tags: rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Given these two active record relation objects

```
cars = Vehicle.where(type: 'car') # ActiveRecord::Relation
motorbikes = Vehicle.where(type: 'motorbike') # ActiveRecord::Relation
```

In what way am I able to combine these two objects into a single object containing both cars and motorbikes that I can use active record methods on? Is it possible?

Edit:
This varies from past questions of a similar nature because I am asking specifically within the context of rails 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails, you could do:

```
cars_and_bikes = Vehicle.where(type: ['car', 'motorbike'])
```

OR using the new Rails 5 `AR#or` you could do:

```
cars_and_bikes = Vehicle.where(type: 'car').or(Vehicle.where(type: 'motorbike'))
```